# Linux make command is deleting a source file

Tags: linux, makefile, rm

I have inherited a project file that has a Makefile in it that is doing something I have never seen before--It is injecting a rm command.  I cannot find any reason for the rm command, so I am missing something very obvious or very esoteric.

Thanks

The results of running make are:

```
bison  --defines --xml --graph=calc.gv -o calc.c calc.y
Bison flags = 
cc    -c -o calc.o calc.c
Making BASE =  calc
cc  -o calc calc.o
Done making BASE
rm calc.c      <======== WHERE IS THIS COMING FROM?
```

The Makefile is:

```
BASE = calc
BISON = bison
XSLTPROC = xsltproc

all: $(BASE)

%.c %.h %.xml %.gv: %.y
    $(BISON) $(BISONFLAGS) --defines --xml --graph=$*.gv -o $*.c $<
    @echo "Bison flags = " $(BISONFLAGS)

$(BASE): $(BASE).o
    @echo "Making BASE = " $(BASE) 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
    @echo "Done making BASE"

run: $(BASE)
    @echo "Type arithmetic expressions.  Quit with ctrl-d."
    ./$<

html: $(BASE).html
%.html: %.xml
    $(XSLTPROC) $(XSLTPROCFLAGS) -o $@ $$($(BISON) --print-datadir)/xslt/xml2xhtml.xsl $<

CLEANFILES = $(BASE) *.o $(BASE).[ch] $(BASE).output $(BASE).xml $(BASE).html $(BASE).gv

clean:
    @echo "Running clean" $(CLEANFILES)
    rm -f $(CLEANFILES)
```

Comment: As explained by Maxim in his answer this is normal behavior, `calc.c` is an intermediate target that you did not request explicitly. I just add that, if you want to keep this target, you can declare it as precious by adding it as a prerequisite of the special target `.PRECIOUS`. Just add the line `.PRECIOUS: calc.c` somewhere in your Makefile.

Comment: It's not a good idea to keep the intermediate file since that will prevent make from rebuilding it when calc.y changes.

Comment: You should not use `.PRECIOUS`.  `.PRECIOUS` is potentially dangerous and should only be used in specific situations and with careful consideration.  You don't need to do that anyway, you just have to list the file as a target or prerequisite _ANYWHERE_.  If you really have no other need for it then something as simple as adding a dummy rule like `make-src: $(BASE).c` will do it.

Comment: Why is `.PRECIOUS` bad: consider if `bison` is in the middle of writing `calc.c` and you use `^C`.  Because you've declared the file `.PRECIOUS`, make will not clean it up for you and you'll have a half-written file with a newer modification time, so re-running make will not rebuild it.  Maybe this will result in an obvious failure but maybe it will result in a subtle failure.  `.PRECIOUS` is only to be used for situations where you want to preserve output even if the build is interrupted.  It really has nothing to do with intermediate files.

Comment: Thank you all for the responses.  I had missed that reference in the documentation about intermediate files even though I had searched for "rm".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Chained-Rules:

> The second difference is that if make does create `b` in order to update something else, it deletes `b` later on after it is no longer needed. Therefore, an intermediate file which did not exist before make also does not exist after make. `make` reports the deletion to you by printing a `rm -f` command showing which file it is deleting.